# android studio - proguard.cfg file is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I want to minimize the size of `.apk` file, so I follow the Android Developer guide (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), but there are some problems I encountered as follows:

I create a new project via Android Studio, but it doesn't generate a `proguard.cfg` file. And there exists a local. Properties file rather than project. Properties file.

How can I figure out this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of the ADT, the file generated is not `proguard.cfg` but `proguard-project.txt`. Proguard must be activated in the file `project.properties`. 
You can check this link: http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements

Comment: In the latest Android Studio version there is no project.properties file.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: So, from where to activate proguard in newer Android studio version?

Comment: @Kushal proguard-rules.pro